# Getting around variable hoisting for callbacks in javascript

Tags: javascript

My understanding of Javascript is that variables have function scope, not block scope, so variables declared inside a block are hoisted to the function above it.  This [article](https://theoreticalideations.com/2012/11/28/variable-hoisting-in-javascript-and-why-you-should-declare-variables-at-the-top/) gives the following code example:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]  
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
  var entry = arr[i];
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(entry);
  }, 100);
}
```

The article states the the code gets translated into the following, and so the variable `entry` is common between each iteration.  The result is that `4` is logged to the console four times

```
var arr, i, len, entry;
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]  
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  
  entry = arr[i];
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(entry);
  }, 100);
}
```

My question is, how should I rewrite the code if I want each call to `setTimeout` to log a different value from `arr`?

Comment: You already can log each value in `arr`

Comment: I've clarified my question, I don't want to simply `for() { console.log(arr[i]) }`

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the `setTimeout` to:

```
setTimeout(
   (function()
      {
          var entry = arr[i];
          return function() {console.log(entry);}
      }
   )()
);
```

That way, you create a new scope, and `entry` is in that scope.

You can also do:

```
(function(e)
    {
        setTimeout(function(){console.log(e);});
    }
)(entry);
```

Which also creates a new scope, in which `e` lies.

Yet another option:

```
setTimeout(
    (function(e)
        {
            return function() {console.log(e);};
        }
    )(entry);
);
```

In all cases, you use an anonymous function that you call immediately, so the only side-effect is that you are creating a new scope.

(edit: reformated a bit for readability, and added a bit more explanations)